# Compact 3-dimensional extension of two-dimensional torus

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

A two-dimensional torus $T^2=S^1\times S^1$ can be extended to a solid torus or so-called toroid which is a topological space equivalent with $D^2\times S^1$. However, such an extension does not treat the two generating cycles of $T^2$ equivalently. For example, one of them will be the boundary of $D^2$ thereby contractible, while the other one is non-contractible. A direct negative result is that not all smooth function on $T^2$ can be extended to this three-dimensional toroid. Therefore, is there any three-dimensional compact manifold $M$ with $\partial M=T^2$, where all the smooth function $T^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ on its boundary $T^2$ can be extended into the ''bulk'' $M$?

Comment: Unless I have made a mistake, every smooth function $F: S^{1} \times S^{1} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ (this is what is usually meant by smooth function if no range is specified) can be extended to the $3$-dimensional toroid. This follows easily from the fact that any two smooth functions on $\mathbb{T^{2}}$ (or any manifold) are homotopic.

Comment: @NickL I am sorry that I forgot to specify the range, which is $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: It would be sufficient to construct a manifold $M$ with boundary $\mathbb{T}^{2}$ such that the inclusion of the boundary induces an isomorphism on $\mathbb{\pi_{1}}$.

Comment: @NickL Yes, you are right, but is there any systematic to do so?

Comment: I don't know, sorry.

Comment: As mentioned in Nick L's answer, $[M, S^1] = \text{Hom}(\pi_1 Y, S^1) = H^1(M;\Bbb Z)$, and being able to extend any map from $\partial M$ to all of $M$ means that the restriction map $[M, S^1] \to [\partial M, S^1]$ is surjective; rephrased, that $H^1(M; \Bbb Z) \to H^1(T^2;\Bbb Z)$ cannot be surjective. In fact, the image is always going to be a $\Bbb Z$ summand of $H^1(T^2;\Bbb Z)$. This is what is known as the 'half-lives, half-dies' principle in 3-manifold topology.

Comment: @MikeMiller Thanks for such an essential principle which answers my question!